# Postgres. Получить значения "год назад" для каждого id

Tags: postgresql

Друзья, добрый день!

Мне необходимо получить из левой таблицы - правую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеются данные по продажам на конкретную дату в разрезе трех id. Мне необходимо получить таблицу, сгруппированную до месяца в разрезе всех id, просумировать продажи и получить "продажи год назад".

Как это посчитать - понятно, но вопрос в производительности. В реальных данных 200 млн. строк и огромное кол-во всех этих id. По хорошему нужно сгруппировать до месяцев, затем сделать cross join всех возможных комбинаций id и дат и к полученному приджойниь продажи и продажи год назад. Но такой запрос не выполняется.

Можно было бы приджойнить просто таблицу саму к себе LEFT JOIN, но тогда не будет создана последняя строка, там где 01.04.2023, т.к. ее нет в исходных данных, такая строка только есть для продаж "года назад". Т.е. такие строки, по которым нет продаж в текущем году, но были год назад тоже должны появиться.

Как делаю сейчас:

```
SELECT    tmp.date,
          tmp.drug_id,
          tmp.region_id,
          tmp.city_id,
          tmp.sale,
          0 AS lag_year_sale,         
FROM   sellout_tmp AS tmp
   UNION ALL
SELECT    tmp.date + interval '1 year' AS lag_year
          tmp.drug_id,
          tmp.region_id,
          tmp.city_id,
          0              AS sale,
          tmp.sale AS lag_year_sale,
FROM   sellout_tmp AS tmp
```

И после этого группирую по всем полям и считаю сумму.

Самый ли это оптимальный вариант? Потому что доросли данные снова до того, что и такой запрос выполняется больше двух часов.

Всем спасибо за советы.

Код для для создания тестовой таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  date DATE,
  drug_id INTEGER,
  region_id INTEGER,
  city_id INTEGER,
  sale INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO sales (date, drug_id, region_id, city_id, sale)
VALUES 
  ('2022-01-01', 1, 1, 1, 100),
  ('2022-02-03', 2, 1, 2, 200),
  ('2022-03-05', 3, 2, 2, 300),
  ('2022-04-10', 4, 2, 2, 400),
  ('2023-01-01', 1, 1, 1, 150),
  ('2023-02-03', 2, 1, 2, 250),
  ('2023-03-05', 3, 2, 2, 350),
  ('2023-05-10', 4, 2, 2, 450);
```

Comment: Предлагаю прикрутить Greenplum или Citus поверх кластера постгрей. Работать будет наверняка намного быстрей.